# How can I keep spambots from getting past multiple web security measures?

Tags: bots, spam

I am trying to stop spam accounts from being created on my website. I run a website that has approximately 50-80k pageviews per month. It's a social media website. Users sign up and communicate with one another for free. We've been battling with spam as of late even though we have implemented multiple security measures to counteract bots. I'd like to get any further suggestions of tips and tricks that I can try and also some help to see if I can identify if these are people coming from clickfarms, etc. (i.e. real people or computers)

**Problem:**
Signup form being completed and users posting spam in their profile information. Spammer signs up for the website by completing the signup form, activates their account via an email account, Logs into their account, and then completes their profile, putting spam in the description box with a link/url to their website they are advertising (everything from @#$%S enlargment to random blogs, to web developer websites, etc.) If there was one link they were posting we could detect it and ban them but they are not -- They are coming from multiple IP's, posting various links, using multiple email provider addresses for activating the accounts, registering with information from multiple countries, and creating about 10-30 accounts per day. Before implementing many security measures we were getting moreso around 100-200 fake accounts per day, but now we're down to 10-30 ... so we've seen some improvement, but the issue is still annoying me. So I'm half thinking now that the security measures are helping quite a bit, but that this is possibly humans still targeting our website and perhaps getting paid per signup they do or something similar to that. Even if so, is there any way I could confirm they are humans versus bots?

**Security measures:**
I won't get into all of the details here (for security reasons), but I'll just indicate what we've done to counteract the spambots:

- Created honeypots at various areas of our website which automatically ban based on IP
- IP banning - based on known botter/spammer ip addresses
- Duration detection of signup form pageload to form submission -- if less than 5 seconds to complete our signup form, we're confirming you're a bot and then preventing the signup
- Hidden checkbox in signup form -- there is a hidden checkbox in the signup form that is invisible to regular users (if a bot checks it we are automatically detecting and preventing the signup)
- Google re-Captcha - We've enabled Google re-Captcha in our signup form as well
- Email activation link - We send our users an activation email with a link that they have to click on to signup  -- they are not able to sign into our website until they've activated their account.

**Future actions include:**

- Detecting what users are posting in their descriptions in their profiles and banning based on that -- string detection for banned words, etc.

Any other suggestions or tips or tricks? In all honesty, if spam bots are getting through all of those security measures above --

- do you think they are just that intelligent?
- do you think we're being targeted?
- Also, any way I can determine if they are bots or real humans? Suggestions?

Comment: Trust me, these are not `SPAM-BOTS`. These are people who have been hired to `SPAM` or are just jobless `SPAMMERS`.

Comment: I second Lance's opinion. Spambots can be pretty intelligent these days (using full-blown headless browsers like PhantomJS), but you are likely attacked by actual humans hired to spam or hoping to earn money through "affiliate programs". As an additional security measure, check the URLs in content posted in databases of known spamvertized domains (URL domain blacklists, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. That is what I feared. PeterK - any suggestions for url domain blacklists I can reference?

Comment: @nmcwilli: Spamhaus DBL, SURBL, uribl.com. These are more geared toward email spam, but _probably_ there's an intersection with web spam (domains are cheap, but not free). Maybe look into WordPress anti-spam plugins to see where they get their data from, there are all sorts of URL reputation services out there.

Comment: How many of these bots do check that invisible checkbox, and imo you can ban those IP's directly, no user is going to check that (but really really make sure they cant do it).
Detection duration time could be 10 seconds, depending on how complex the form is, but usually combination of email and password takes more than 5s

Answer (score 1):

This is a perennial problem; over the years I've found that as I add more anti-spam measures, the spammers continually get better at circumventing my measures.

I recommend doing an analysis of your spam to figure out how you can detect it. The spam itself contains the key to how to outsmart it. Look at the patterns, the structure, and decide what information is most useful and how the easiest way is to filter it out. Your spam detection doesn't need to be perfect, but generally, you want to get as much as possible, while getting as few false positives as possible.

Also, to answer your one question, you can make your bot-detection perfect, but there will always be humans submitting spam. And humans are tough to outsmart, and you may always need some manual attention to do it.

You are already implementing a lot of measures. Here are some more I would suggest:

- When a signup form is generated, put a hidden field with a unique hash generated from the user's browser info, including the user's IP, HTTP user agent, and the date. Then, when the form is submitted, check the hash. This one method eliminated a surprising amount of spam.
- If you want to take the previous method even farther, use a custom, time-sensitive hash in the URL of your contact form, and have the link to this form be dynamically generated. This way, if a spammer stores the form's URL, it won't work, but the link will work for every legitimate user of the site.
- Make it so newly created, non-trusted users, cannot display any public profile information, such as URL's or text even. With a site as small as yours you could require manual approval of each user, and if your userbase got bigger, you could use an automated reputation system, a lot like Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites use. This removes the incentive for spam. Also, I found an overwhelming majority of spammers only ever logged onto the site once. If you wait to do the manual approval of users, until they have logged on twice, or even have returned to the site on another day, using a persistent cookie, you will filter out the vast majority of spammers and you will only have to do a small amount of manual approval work. Then have the system delete the unvalidated/inactive accounts after a certain amount of time.
- Check for certain keywords or structure of info. I found an overwhelming majority of my spammers would use certain words or phrases that were *never used* by my legitimate users. Another one was entering a phone number in their profile, a common pattern in spammers, that no legitimate user ever did. Also look for signs of foul play like XSS attacks. A huge portion of spammers will, at some point, submit something that has a ton of HTML tags in it, you can either use the tags itself to filter them out, or you can do something like stripping the HTML tags and then comparing string length and banning them if it's more than a small amount (i.e. allow someone to do something simple like a few `<em></em>` or `<strong></strong>` tags.) Usually, if there are HTML tags in the entry, there's a ton of it. Also look for material with weird encodings or characters that don't make sense. This is often an attempt at sophisticated SQL injection attacks, XSS, or other types of hacking attempts.
- Use external IP blacklists. AbuseIPDB is one example; it has an API that you can use to check new IP's before storing them in your temporary database. Their free plan allows checking of up to 1000 IP's a day and you can pay for more than that. It won't catch all the manual spam but I find they catch a ton of the automated spam.

Are they targeting you? Yes. They are targeting everyone. But any site with 50k+ pageviews a month is high enough volume to be an attractive target. The higher traffic you get, the more attractive of a target you will be. Even some of my tiny sites have been targeted with suprisingly sophisticated attacks these days. Everyone needs to be on guard.

Good luck. I wish this weren't so much of a problem, but it is.